# Javascript extension autofill filled input values dissapear on click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, automation, autofill

I have tried making my extension fill a form with this code:

```
var email = document.querySelector("#email");
email.value = "email@email.com";
var password = document.querySelector("#password");
password.value = "password";

var birthmonth = document.querySelector("birthmonth");
var birthday = document.querySelector("birthday");
birthmonth.value = "3";
birthday.value = "5";
```

It fills email and password box without any problems. But, when I click on other input field other than this which I filled and manually type something, the inputs filled with my extension are being cleared and they are empty.

I also noticed that if I will fill that form completely with my extension it doesn't let me submit it, like those value inputs from my extension are not counting.

Is this a some kind of security feature of this webpage? Or is it my fault and I'am doing something wrong?
Thanks for help!

Comment: We need to see more core. The code you submitted works: https://jsfiddle.net/6zathL0q/5/

Comment: Yes, indeed this code works fine when I run it in enviroment like above, but when I try to run it in targeted  site it does autofill inputs, but it does not let me submit it, when I try to manually change the value of the input by just typing into it entire form clears. It treats the  action of .value as just visuals and doesn't apply it anywhere else.

Comment: The "form" is actually not a form by tag meanings, because it's builded with divs that have input and buttons inside. I've tried filling value by using selector path and Xpath, it does fill the input field with value, but doesn't do anything else, I think that the page javascript running along doesn't record that value as it should, thus it doesn't let me submit the form.